# probability of 3 heads from x number of coin flips, corresponding to value x rolled on die- Intuition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we roll a fair six-sided die and then flip a number of fair coins equal to
the number showing on the die. (For example, if the die shows 4, then we flip 4 coins.)
(a) What is the probability that the number of heads equals 3?

My answer to this question was $$\begin{aligned}&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=3}^6{\frac{k!}{3!(k-3)!\times2^k}}\\&=\frac{1}{6}\end{aligned}$$ Its clear that the sum converges into 1, but I don't get the intuition behind it. Or is my calculator rounding the summation to 1. Or even worse, is my solution wrong. Somebody explain why the probability ends up being 1/6. I know how to get the answer, but 1/6 seems like a very specific nice looking number. Why is the probability specifically 1/6.

Comment: As for "*why*"... is a coincidence and this just happened to be the value calculated not a good enough reason?  If you were to repeat the problem but ask for the probability that the number of heads shown is $2$... do you get $\frac{1}{6}$ as well?  No?  Well then... what is so special about $3$ that it "gave a nice answer" while $2$ didn't?  Nothing particularly...

Comment: On the other hand, when using an 8 sided dice the probability for getting 4 heads is $1/8$.  Guess what happens when you use a 10 sided die? Congratulations, you have found an identity.  $$\sum_{k=n}^{2n} 2^{-k}\dbinom{k}{n}=1$$